# Forbidden resource in API group at the cluster scope

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, minikube

I am unable to identify what the exact issue with the permissions with my setup as shown below. I've looked into all the similar QAs but still unable to solve the issue. The aim is to deploy Prometheus and let it **scrape** `/metrics` endpoints that my other applications in the cluster expose fine.

```sh
Failed to watch *v1.Endpoints: failed to list *v1.Endpoints: endpoints is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:default\" cannot list resource \"endpoints\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope"
Failed to watch *v1.Pod: failed to list *v1.Pod: pods is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:default\" cannot list resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope"
Failed to watch *v1.Service: failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:default\" cannot list resource \"services\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope"
...
...
```

The command below returns `no` to all services, nodes, pods etc.

```sh
kubectl auth can-i get services --as=system:serviceaccount:default:default -n default
```

**Minikube**

```sh
$ minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox --extra-config=apiserver.Authorization.Mode=RBAC

  minikube v1.14.2 on Darwin 11.2
✨  Using the virtualbox driver based on existing profile
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Restarting existing virtualbox VM for "minikube" ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.19.2 on Docker 19.03.12 ...
    ▪ apiserver.Authorization.Mode=RBAC
  Verifying Kubernetes components...
  Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass, dashboard
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" by default
```

**Roles**

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole

metadata:
  name: monitoring-cluster-role

rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["nodes", "services", "pods", "endpoints"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["configmaps"]
    verbs: ["get"]
  - apiGroups: ["extensions"]
    resources: ["deployments"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount

metadata:
  name: monitoring-service-account
  namespace: default
```

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding

metadata:
  name: monitoring-cluster-role-binding

roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: monitoring-cluster-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io

subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: monitoring-service-account
    namespace: default
```

**Prometheus**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
 
metadata:
  name: prometheus-config-map
  namespace: default
 
data:
  prometheus.yml: |
    global:
      scrape_interval: 15s
    scrape_configs:
      - job_name: 'kubernetes-service-endpoints'
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: endpoints
        relabel_configs:
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_namespace
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_name
```

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
 
metadata:
  name: prometheus-deployment
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: prometheus
 
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prometheus
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: prometheus
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: prometheus
          image: prom/prometheus:latest
          ports:
            - name: http
              protocol: TCP
              containerPort: 9090
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config
              mountPath: /etc/prometheus/
            - name: storage
              mountPath: /prometheus/
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: prometheus-config-map
        - name: storage
          emptyDir: {}
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
 
metadata:
  name: prometheus-service
  namespace: default
 
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: prometheus
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9090
```

Comment: I had the same issue with metal-lb and I had to enable rbac in values.yaml in the helm chart.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list resource "endpoints" in API group "" at the cluster scope"

> User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope"

> User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list resource "services" in API group "" at the cluster scope"

Something running with ServiceAccount `default` in namespace `default` is doing things it does not have permissions for.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: monitoring-service-account
```

Here you create a specific ServiceAccount. You also give it some Cluster-wide permissions.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: prometheus-deployment
  namespace: default
```

You run Prometheus in namespace `default` but do not specify a specific ServiceAccount, so it will run with ServiceAccount `default`.

I think your problem is that you are supposed to set the ServiceAccount that you create in the Deployment-manifest for Prometheus.

Comment: You are right. All I had to do is add `serviceAccountName: monitoring-service-account` to `spec.spec` of deployment manifest. Thanks.